# insert query on a custom table using ajax with jQuery plugin Jeditable

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, ajax, query

I've read tons of post already but found no solution...

I'm tryin to implement [Jeditable](https://plugins.jquery.com/jeditable/) functionality in a plugin with this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.edit').editable('http://localhost/www/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/save.php'
});
```

If in `save.php` I simply echo something, it will be returned to the textfield I was updating without problem. Problem is on how to insert it into the db... If I use this:

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    global $wpdb;
    $query = "INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('%d', '%s', '%d')";
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($query, '10', $_post['value'], '0'));
    echo $_POST['value'];
}
```

I get the following error:

> "FATAL ERROR: CALL TO A MEMBER FUNCTION QUERY() ON A NON-OBJECT IN [...] ON LINE 6"

(line 6 is `$wpdb->query([...]);`).

Now, what I understend from other posts is that I can't call `save.php` directly from AJAX. What I didn't get is how else should I do it. I tried all the solutions of those posts and read the official [Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the WordPress [AJAX-API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) for those purposes instead of custom scripts. Your problem is, that in your script all the WordPress API-Objects are not loaded.

[Here is an answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/126896/31323) which describe the usage of the AJAX-API in a very similar case. There, a post is inserted to the database in the `wpse_126886_ajax_handler()` function. On the same way, you can of cause run any other query you want.

*Edit due to new information from comments:*

You could have mentioned, that »Jeditable« is a plugin for jQuery and there's a documentation for it.

Anyway, the [documentation](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) (Section: »Parameter reference«) of the jQuery plugin describes a way, you can pass more parameters to your script. But first of all, let me explain, how to enqueue your scripts and how to pass data (e.g. the `nonce` slug) to it:

```
/**
 * enqueue jquery, jquery-jeditable and custom script
 * and pass some data to
 *
 * @wp-hook wp_enqueue_scripts
 * @return void
 */
function wpse_135219_enqueue_scripts() {

    wp_register_script(
        'jquery-jeditable',
        plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/jquery-jeditable.js',
        array( 'jquery' ),
        '1.7.1',
        TRUE
    );

    wp_register_script(
        'wpse-135219',
        plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/wpse-135219.js',
        array( 'jquery-jeditable' ),
        '1.7.1',
        TRUE
    );

    $script_settings = array(
        'ajaxUrl' => home_url( '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' ),
        'nonce'   => wp_create_nonce( 'wpse_135219' ),
        'action'  => 'wpse_135219'
    );
    wp_localize_script(
        'wpse-135219',
        'wpSE135219',
        $script_settings
    );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'wpse-135219' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_135219_enqueue_scripts' );
```

These function resides in a plugin file named `wpse-135221.php`. The plugins file structure looks like this:

```
- wpse-135219-plugin/
--- js/
----- jquery-jeditable.js
----- wpse-135219.js
--- wpse-135219.php
```

With `wp_localize_script()` you initialize a global javascript object named `wpSE135219` where you find your nonce and even the ajax URL.

Here's an example on how to use it with Jeditable (`wpse-135219.js`):

```
( function( $ ) {
    'use strict';

    $( document ).ready( function() {
        var settings  = wpSE135219,
            params    = {
                wp_nonce : settings.nonce,
                action   : settings.action
            };

        $( '.edit' ).editable( settings.ajaxURL, {
            submitdata : params
        } );
    } );

} )( jQuery );
```

Now you have the following request parameter:

```
action    "wpse_135219"
id        "your_html_id"
value     "your_value"
wp_nonce  "3bd42174ec" // a wp nonce string
```

As shown in the referred answer above, the action you've to attach your ajax handler on must be `admin_ajax_wpse_135219`:

```
add_action( 'admin_ajax_your_form_action', 'wpse_135219_ajax_handler' );
function wpse_135219_ajax_handler() {
    // your query stuff goes here
    // don't forget to check $_POST[ 'wp_nonce' ]
}
```

To verify the request with the nonce use [`wp_verify_nonce()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_verify_nonce)

Comment: i've already read that post before posting. it's the first time that i use Ajax so maybe it's because of this, but i really can't understand what to do...what is this slug and where should i put it?! jeditable is not a for in where i can add an hidden field. also, the function is passing correctly the parameters...why can't i execute a simple query?

Comment: @Mariano This is a really good answer, and documented too, you should follow it, and do some documentation on how to write ajax in wordpress so that you can use the wordpress native functions/classes.

Comment: @Mariano I didn't know »Jeditable« plugin before you mentioned it in your comment. So I've updated my answer.

Comment: hi, thanks for your time...i made some try reading and reading the codex page again and i finally found the solution.
again, thanks for your help.